# How can I remove two partitions on my USB?

Tags: 14.04

I have a usb with two partitions:

- the 1st is /dev/sdb/
- and the second is /dev/sdc/

The two partitions are "read only permission". I try to remove this partitions and make a normal usb with programs like "gparted, disk..." but I can't. Someone help me please.

Comment: Firstly, read-only on USB's often means the write-protect switch is set. Secondly, and perhaps more important, /dev/sdb & /dev/sdc will NOT both be the same USB stick! Do *not* delete them without checking what they really are - unplug / re-plug it & type `dmesg | tail` in terminal to find out which is the USB!

Comment: post the output of `fdisk -l`

Comment: sdb and sdc are not two different partitions on the same drive -- they are two entirely different drives.

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities I can think of are:

1. You are doing something very wrong. It is telling that you mention /dev/sdb and /dev/sdc. Those are normally different devices entirely, meaning that one of those *is not your USB stick*. Partitions would be e.g. /dev/sdb0 and /dev/sdb1. So make sure you are dealing with the devices you think you are. You may wish to take a look at the output of `dmesg` for some information about which device is which (e.g. `dmesg | grep sdb` and `dmesg | grep sdc` before and after inserting your stick).
2. You are not root, but you need to be, or at least you need to be logged in as some user that has write access to those /dev nodes.
3. If these partitions are part of the out-of-the-box configuration, often manufacturers will create a special partition for their own software and, via special programming in the controller, will not let you remove these partitions. Cruzer, for example, is particularly bad with this in my experience. In this case, there is nothing you can do.
4. If your USB stick has a write protect switch (relatively rare these days), turn it off. However, if you can currently write files to the existing partitions without issue, then that rules out this problem.
5. If your USB stick has failed or is about to fail, many manufacturers add code to the firmware to kick the stick into permanent read-only mode when failure is imminent. If this is the case, there is nothing you can do. However, if you can currently write files to the stick without issue, then that also rules out this problem.

Of all the possible causes, those 5 are the most common. I believe 1 or 3 would be the most likely causes in your case.